# Verifying username/password via MySQL server using PDO functions

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am having some problem connecting properly to the MySQL server using the PDO function.
I can't query what I need from the database and I am not quite sure what PDO functions to use.
I GET 0 as a result of this.
I wish to verify the password and username I enter via the database and make an if statement that launches the session if the information is correct.

Here is my  UPDATED code:

```
<?php
// if a value is given
if (isset($_POST['username' && 'password'));
{

    // starts the session created if login info is correct
    session_start();

    // connectivity to MySQL server
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=name', 'username', 'password');

    // information entered in form made into a variable
    $username = PDO::quote($_POST['username']); 
    $password = PDO::quote($_POST['password']);

    // after pressing login, checking if the variables exist in the database
    if ($_POST['button'] == 'Login')
    {
        $query = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM login WHERE username=:username AND password=:password");
        $query->bindValue(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindValue(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute();

        // Check the number of rows that match the SELECT statement 
        if($query = $db->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) 
        {
            echo "No records found";
        }
        else
        {
            header("Location: members.php");
            $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
        }
    }   
    // After pressing register, stores variable and adds it in register field
    else if ($_POST['register'] == 'Register')
    {
        header("Location: register.php");
        $_SESSION['usernamereg'] = $_POST['username'];
    }

    // If no button is pressed, send to index
    else
    {
        header("Location: http://www.gjertgjersund.com");
    }

// closes the if value is given statement
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Folder </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="frontpage.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="box">
    <div id="wrap">


        <center>
        <img src="./img/logo.png" alt="logo">

        <form action='index.php' method='POST' autocomplete='off'>

        <div class="usernameform">
        <input type='text' name='username' style='border: none; font-size: 20px;'>
        </div>

        <br />

        <div class="passwordform">
        <input type='password' name='password' style='border: none; font-size: 20px;'>
        </div>

        <br />

        <div class="registerlogin">
        <input type='submit' name='button' value='Login' class='input'>
        <input type='submit' name='register' value='Register' class='inputtwo'>
        </div>

        </form>
        </center>

    </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *Please* don't store plain text passwords in your database.

Comment: My username and password is set as varchar in the database. Should I use an encryption that encrypts the $username and $password and checks it with the encrypted username and password in the database?

Comment: You should not encrypt it. But you should [hash the password](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Is that something that can easly be done after I have made the connection possible first?

Comment: Yes. As long as you do it and not say meh it works now. ;)

Comment: True that, still trying to figure out PDO though, made the stupid mistake of learning to use mysql_ functions and then I read they where out of date :S

Comment: "I just rewrote my old bad mysql code to new equally bad PDO code, plesae rewiew it" is a most popular question under PDO tag. Just musing.

Comment: Well, it is either having a bad mysql code that gets thrown away soon or having a bad PDO code that last for another couple of years... so I choosed to rewise some PDO....

Answer (score 1):

That's a very good question, partially because it demonstrates a lot of bad practices that, sadly, exist to this day, almost a decade since this question has been posted. Let's sort them out

## Connection

> I am having some problem connecting properly to the MySQL server using the PDO function.

That's a fair question and nowhere the connection is just a single line of code. Мany important options have to be set, see a [canonical connection example](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql) I wrote. You can store the connection code in a separate file and then just include it in your scripts.

## Password hashing

You should never store plain passwords in your database. Instead, password must be *hashed*, using a dedicated function made for the purpose - [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).

Then, to verify the password, you've go to use `password_verify()`

Don't move any further until you have your passwords properly hashed. Note that the field size for the hashed password must be 60 characters long.

## The code to verify username and password

Finally, now we can write the code. It could be much simpler, just a few lines. Actually, only one condition is needed. We shouldn't provide any details as to whether login or username not found - just "Login and password don't match". So here it goes:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['username']))
{
    // get the PDO instance
    include 'pdo.php';

    // getting the record for the given username
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username=?");
    $stmt->execute([$_POST['username']]);
    $user = $stmt->fetch();
    // verifying the password
    if ($user && password_verify($_POST['password'], $user['password']))
    {
        // starts the session created if login info is correct
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['username'] = $user['username'];
        header("Location: members.php");
        exit;
    } else {
        $error = "Login and password don't match";
    }
}
```

Here, we are checking whether such a user exists and whether the password matches in a single condition.

Comment: there is no code that may output 0. you are running some other code probably

Comment: Well I replaced the code you gave me and put it into my code, but still outputs 0 so obviously there is something that outputs 0.

Comment: Well I know it can't be the forms in the HTML, because I have viewed them thousand times now. So must be the if statement that runs if submit buttons are pressed... can you see any error?

Comment: New Update: I run a error check and it says there is something wrong with my execute.... I am using the code you provided... is there something that can cause a error?

Comment: Hmmm, now it is giving me an error regarding: `if($db->fetchColumn()===$_POST['password'])`. This is the message `Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::fetchColumn()`

Comment: Are you able to identify this problem? :)

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to use `'` in prepared statement and `$username` is string not integer

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username=:username AND password=:password");
$query->bindValue(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$row_count = $query->rowCount();
 //{ remove it
```

Your `if` condition is wrong change

```
// if a value is given
if (isset($_POST['username' && 'password'));
{
```

to

```
// if a value is given
if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password']))
{
```

[Codepad](http://codepad.org/UfRed0ms)

Comment: So how would you make the query for the server?

Comment: @FriedBitz It all handled by prepared statement

Comment: where have you putted code for printing the `0`? See edited answer. You forgot to execute the query.

Comment: Nowhere, that the problem... I changed what you told me to, and use the code I posted above with the changes. When I bring it online I can only see 0 when I go on my site. I tried it, still showing 0. Go to http://www.gjertgjersund.com/ to see

Comment: @FriedBitz Its showing `0` for other page as well. I think it is your server problem. Contact your server provider.

Comment: Hmmm okai, I am contacting the server provider now :)

Comment: Server provider said the code was script related from my side. I updated the code here, is it correct? at my site is shows 0

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This answer is the _closest_ to a correct answer so far. Just be aware that [rowCount() cannot be depended upon](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php).

Comment: Thank you, it is working now @YogeshSuthar , what are you meaning about rowCount() cannot be depended upon?

Comment: Sorry, the form appeared, but once the Login button was pressed it gave me 0 again... why is that?

Comment: @FriedBitz put error_reporting on and view the error. I think when your code contains error it shows 0.

Comment: put this code at start of script `ini_set('display_errors', 1);error_reporting(E_ALL);`.

Answer (score 0):

Some databases may return the number of rows returned by a SELECT statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on see [**Manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php). You can use `COUNT(*)` and `fetchColumn()` as in following query to emulate `rowCount()`.

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM login WHERE username=:username AND password=:password");
$query->bindValue(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
    // Check the number of rows that match the SELECT statement 
    if($query->fetchColumn() == 0) {
        echo "No records found";
     }else{
            //CODE FOR Success 
            //Etc
    }
```

Comment: this makes absolutely no sense. Why 2 queries? Why everyone so much inclined to this useless count?

Comment: Look, David. You are one of a few sane people here and it makes this code looks more surprising to me. This answer of yours is rather mechanical than helpful. To verify a person you never need a count, neither using SQL nor PDO. You rather need a record itself. And as you need it anyway, there is no use for count - you can get both existence flag and details in one query. So, if you ever need this flag - just select * and use `if ($row)` to see if anything were found.